# Excel VBA: sort method of range class failed

Tags: excel, vba, range

I know there are several threads on this topic but none of the answers have helped resolve this error. I have a VBA form and it was running fine before but something changed and it's giving me the following errors first one is "sort method of range class failed"

```
Sub Show_Form()
    
    frmForm.Show

End Sub
```

I am suspecting this line of code

```
Range("L2").Sort Key1:=Range("L2"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

Comment: Record a macro, extract the generated code and adapt it as needed.

Comment: Well, I just started using VBA and don't know how to do that is there any other way you could help? below is the sheet that I am using to sort the data according to the visit date which is starting from "L2".
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

Answer (score 0):

The code you suspect isn't included in the code you offer. In plain English: you aren't showing us the relevant code.

However, you are right. `Range("L2").Sort` must indeed fail because you can't sort a single cell. The purpose of that line of code is to identify the range of columns to be sorted. `Range("A:Z").Sort` would be fine, with `Key1:=Range("L2")` next specifying that you want to sort on column L. Here, too, the indicated row is ignored and `Key1:=Columns(12)` or `Key1:=Columns("L")` fulfilling the task. However, if you want to sort only a single column you must specify a range, like, `Range("L2:L2000").Sort`. I agree, it isn't entirely logical but, looking from another side, it is.

The full range is supplied a little later in the code when the `SetRange` property is set. That's when all rows ***and*** columns are relevant. Make sure that the column specified in the `Kwy` property is included in the range to be sorted.

Comment: Well I tried what you said (lack of understanding on my part) it removed the error but it didn't to any sorting.
`Range("A2:L2").Sort Key1:=Range("L2:L2000"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
`
If you can help me by writing the code so that I might understand it clearly.
I have a database sheet with columns range (A:L) with the first row the headings. I have a column " L" which is a visit date so whenever the application is run it should sort the rows according to the latest visit first and show it in the Listbox.
hope you understand what is my aim. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you're not showing your code I have to guess and I guessed wrong. Sorry. To understand what I'm talking about record a macro while you sort the range A2:L2000 manually. Your code is a shorter version of what you will see. Try amending it by declaring the entire range as the base but set the `Key` to a single column: `Range("A2:L2000").Sort Key1:=Range("L2"), etc`. Your column headers might be in row 1, hence not included in the specified range, hence `Headers:=xlNo` (or start the range from row 1).

Comment: On the developer pane, click on macro, record. Do whatever you want to do, in your case sort. Click stop recording. Open VBA and look for the macro that got recorded. Modify as per your needs.

Comment: It's working now but the problem is it's sorting the first column (Serial# 1,2,3,4...) so now its looks like Serial# 4,2,3,1... I don't want that as it looks wrong in the Listbox.
Any suggestion?

`With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Range("A2:L2000").Sort Key1:=Range("L2:L2000"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
End With`

Comment: Consider `Order1:=xlAscending`